# WordPress Asymmetrical Grid

Tags: wordpress, post, grid

My client is requesting the following grid for their WordPress blog. Every 4th post will be fullwidth. Would I just use a css nth selecter to do this? Or is it not that simple?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use css nth child, but better practice would be to do it with a counter on the php loop you're already using to query the posts. Using the modulo operation, you could distinguish between each fourth item and the rest using different css classes.
For example:

```html
<div class="posts-grid">
      <?php 
        $counter=1; 
        $class=null; 
        $posts=g et_posts( 'numberposts=-1&order=ASC'); 
        foreach( $posts as $post ) :
          if ($counter % 4==0 ) { 
            $class= full-width; 
          } else { 
            $class= third-width; 
          } 
      ?>
        <div class="post-item <?php echo $class; ?>">
          ...
        </div>

      <?php $counter++; endforeach; ?>
</div>
```